# Is there a 'caps-lock-mode' for those of us who've rebound the key?

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

Rebinding your caps-lock key to control is a popular thing to do (though there are arguments against it, even if a bit pedantic).  However, the language I find a lot of my time in uses runs of capitals pretty extensively.

Is there a `caps-lock-mode` that can simulate the behavior?  (Without affecting existing keybindings of course, e.g. striking `C-x C-s` will not send `C-X C-S`.)

Comment: You can always use M-u (`upcase-word`) and C-x C-u (`upcase-region`). With a negative prefix arg you could upcase some number of words that you just typed, e.g. M-- M-4 M-u to upcase the last four words.

Comment: @glucas That's what I've been doing (`upcase-region`), but it's not quite the same.

Comment: Yeah - does seem like having an upcase minor mode you could toggle would be more convenient in such cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the [`caps-lock`](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/caps-lock.html) minor mode package:

```
Summary: Caps-lock as a minor mode
Homepage: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/caps-lock.html
```